# i followed a tutorial that was supposed to make a wave but it didnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css

i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/shorts/VTw2cUVFl1c
but it doesnt want to work, can someone help?
`

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.liquid {
  height: max(300px, 30vw);
  width: max(300px, 30vw);
  background-color: rgb(33, 150, 243);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  animation: wave 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes wave {
  from, to {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
  }
}
```

```
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

function animateBubble(x) {  
  const bubble = document.createElement("div");
  
  bubble.className = "liquid";
  bubble.style.left = `${x}px`;
  
  wrapper.appendChild(liquid);
  
  setTimeout(() => wrapper.removeChild(liquid), 2000);
}

window.onmousemove = e => animateBubble(e.clientX);
```

the tutorial was supposed to make a wave animation but nothing happend
im new to html css and js so i couldnt really do anything

Comment: You are using liquid as a variable in `wrapper.appendChild(liquid)`, but where do you define liquid?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append child `liquid` in your JS but there is no variable called `liquid` there. The `liquid` is a class on the `bubble` variable.

To fix your code, your JS needs to look like this:

```
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

function animateBubble(x) {
    const bubble = document.createElement("div");

    bubble.className = "liquid";
    bubble.style.left = `${x}px`;

    wrapper.appendChild(bubble); // This is where the bubble variable is passed as a prop to `wrapper.appendChild` method.

    setTimeout(() => wrapper.removeChild(liquid), 2000);
}

window.onmousemove = (e) => animateBubble(e.clientX);
```